# How to retrieve data from database using jQuery Ajax calling a Django view

Tags: python, jquery, django

I would like to fetch data from my database on `document.ready` using jQuery-ajax.

I am trying it with the below logic, but somehow it can't reach the server:

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/terminal/getStocksAvailable/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**jQuery async database call**

```
// on pageload query availableStocks via jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax("getStocksAvailable/", {
        method: "GET",
        async: "True",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var stocksAvailable = response;
            console.log(stocksAvailable);
        }
    });
});
```

**urls.py**

```
from terminal.views import getStocksInfo, getStocksAvailable

urlpatterns = [

    [...]

    # database fetch views
    path('terminal/getStocksAvailable/', getStocksAvailable),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from feeder.models import StocksAvailableModel

def getStocksAvailable(request, *args, **kwargs):
    stocksAvailable = serializers.serialize('json', StocksAvailableModel.objects.values('description'))
    return HttpResponse(StocksAvailable)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just be a typo in `getStocksAvailable`, you have written `StocksAvailable` with a capital S, when it should be a lower case s.

With regards to your comment:

> "but somehow it can't reach the server"

Note a 500 error doesn't mean it can't reach the server, rather that it has reached the server and something has gone wrong. It is helpful to look at the output from your server to diagnose an issue like this. Since this is being run locally, I'm assuming you've got a terminal where you have run `python manage.py runserver`. Look at the output in this terminal.

Also, depending on the data you're returning, django also has a `JsonResponse` object that is often more apropriate for AJAX responses.